# Waiting for an unknown number of asynchronous tasks

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a queue of tasks, and a thread that peek the queue once in a few seconds and if there is a task it performs it.

I have another code section (in another thread of course), that creates tasks in a loop (I can't know the number of tasks in advance from outside the loop) and insert them to the queue. The tasks contains some 'result' object, and the external thread (which created those tasks) need to wait for all the tasks to finish and finally get the result from each one of them.
The problem is that I can't pass java Semaphore\CountDownLatch etc to the result object since I don't know the number of monitors in advance. 
I also can't use an Executor that uses invokeAll or wait for the Future object since the tasks are unsynchrnized (the external thread just pust the task to a queue and another thread will execute the task when he have time for this).

The only solution I've had in mind is to create some 'Inverted Semaphore' class that holds a set of results and a monitors counter. The getResult function will check if the counter == 0 and if the answer is yes will notify some lock object, and the getResult function will wait for this lock:

```
public class InvertedSemaphore<T> {
    Set<T> resultSet;
    int usages;
    final Object c;

    public InvertedSemaphore() {
        resultSet = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<T>());
        usages = 0;
        c = new Object();
    }

    public void addResult(T result) {
        resultSet.add(result);
    }

    public void addResults(Set<T> result) {
        resultSet.addAll(result);
    }


    public void acquire() {
        usages++;
    }

    public void release() {
        synchronized (c) {
            if (--usages == 0) {
                c.notify();
            }
        }
    }

    public Set<T> getResults() {
        synchronized (c) {
            try {
                while (usages > 0) {
                    c.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return resultSet;
    }

}
```

Each addTask method will invoke semaphore.acquire, and each of the (unsynchronized) tasks will invoke semaphore.release in the end of the task.

It sounds pretty complicated and I'm pretty sure there is a better solution for this in java concurrent library or something.

Any idea will be appriciated:)

Comment: Sounds like you need a `CountUpLatch`. :)

Answer (score 4):

If the tasks don't need to be processed in order, use an [ExecutorCompletionService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html)

More generally, it is not necessary to use `invokeAll` on an `ExecutorService` in order to get a `Future` for the result. `ExecutorService#submit` could be used for this purpose, or optionally, the task being created could implement `Future` itself, thus allowing the creator of the task to ask for the result at a later point in time.

Some code:

```
class MyTask {
    AtomicReference<?> result = new AtomicReference<?>();

    void run() {
       //do stuff here
       result.set(/* the result of the calculation */);
    }

    boolean resultReady() {
        return result.get()!=null;
    }

    ? get() {
        return result.get();
    }
}
```

... elsewhere in code

```
void createTasks() {
    Collection<MyTask> c = new ...;

    while(indeterminable condition) {
        MyTask task = new MyTask();
        c.add(task);
        mysteryQueue.add(task);
    }

    while(haven't received all results) {
        MyTask task = c.get(...); //or iterate or whatever
        ? result = task.get();
        if (result!=null) {
            //do stuff, probably remove the task from the collection c would be smart
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the problem with the Executors is that the 'task' that the executer will perform is just to put the real task in some queue - and these task will be executed by a different thread in an usynchronic way. I need to wait for the 'real' tasks results so I can indeed check once in a while if the results are there already but I don't even know if I'll have a results. I have to know when all the asynchronic tasks are done and only then try to get the results.

Comment: Well that's just silly. But it doesn't prevent you from implementing `Future` yourself or providing some way of getting back at the result via the interface of the "real task"

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to use a separate queue for the results.
So you will have one blocking queue that thread `A` places tasks for thread `B` thereby having a producer-consumer approach, and when each task is completed, the result could be placed in the *second* result queue inverting the consumer-producer roles since now thread `A` that originally created the tasks will consume the result from the second queue.

Comment: Yeah but I need to do some operation on the results and I won't know when the results queue will be considered as 'full'.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Thread `A` knows how many tasks it has inserted in the queue that thread `B` is a consumer. Now thread `A` as long as there is a task in the result queue it consumes it. If there is no task and has not already consumed all results (it knows how much it placed on the first queue, so `A` knows how much it is supposed to consume) it either waits for results or does other processing

Comment: @axelrod, yes you can, the same way you would check the counter in your idea of the reverse semaphore. Something puts an initial value there and something decrements it-this means that you know how to establish that you may continue some other execution based on the completion of a certain number of tasks.

Comment: The problem is that thread A is not the only one who insert tasks to thread B's queue... Thread A only needs the results of his tasks.

Comment: @Vitaly, can you elaborate where to put the value? I didn't exactly understood your answer. Thanks

Comment: @axelrod:You should have specified that in your OP.But I don't see what's the problem. You can keep a `job` counter that you atomically increment each time a thread places a task and that thread `A` atomically checks and decrements each times it consumes a result. So thread `A` can actually know how much task results should expect

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:
each producer will hold its own queue. The producer will pass a means to report to this queue to the Task itself. When the task finishes running, it will queue its result to this queue. It is beast described by some code:

```
class Result{}

interface IResultCallback{
    void resultReady(Result r); // this is an abstraction of the queue
}

class Producer implements IResultCallback{ 
    // the producer needs to pass itself to the constructor of the task,
    // the task will only see its "resultReady" facade and will be able to report to it. 
    // the producer can aggragte the results at it will and execute its own computation as 
        // as soon it is ready

    Queue<Result> results; // = init queue

    @Override
    public void resultReady(Result r) {
        results.add(r);

        if(results.size() == 9){
            operate();
        }
        results.clear();
    }

    public void operate(){
        // bla bla
    }
}

public class Task {
    IResultCallback callback;

    public Task(IResultCallback callback){
        this.callback = callback;
    }
    public void execute(){
        // bla bla

        Result r = null; // init result;
        callback.resultReady(r);
    }
}
```

Comment: @axelrod Good luck! Don't forget to be a good denizen of StackOverflow and vote / accept the answer :-)